# I need help deleting a image from a canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I need help, i'm trying to delete a character when you press the left arrow key and then make a new one. I cant get my finger around deleting the character though. Here is my code:

```html
  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var c = canvas.getContext('2d');
  canvas.width = 1000;
  canvas.height = 600;
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);

  var NANONAUT_HEIGHT = 10;
  var NANONAUT_WIDTH = 240;

  window.addEventListener('keydown', onKeyDown);
//  window.addEventListener('keyup', onKeyUp);

  function onKeyDown(event) {
   if(event.keyCode === 39){ 
    if(NANONAUT_HEIGHT <= 240){
      NANONAUT_HEIGHT = NANONAUT_HEIGHT + 10

      for(i = NANONAUT_HEIGHT; i < img.width; i++){
    c.drawImage(nanonaut, NANONAUT_HEIGHT, NANONAUT_WIDTH)
      }
    }
   } 
     console.log(NANONAUT_WIDTH)
  }



  var nanonaut = new Image();
  nanonaut.src = "https://cdn.glitch.com/098e8cf0-b83e-44bc-8aa2-c8316900937f%2FNanonaut.png?1551809807699"
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = "https://cdn.glitch.com/098e8cf0-b83e-44bc-8aa2-c8316900937f%2Fimage.png?1551724673489"

  c.drawImage(img, 10,10);
  c.drawImage(nanonaut, NANONAUT_HEIGHT, NANONAUT_WIDTH)
```

Sorry if it looks noobish, i just started with canvas's. I've tried clearRect but that removes the img too. Any help would be appreciated! (Website is https://project-experiment.glitch.me/ if you wanna see. (You need to refresh it 2 times to see the images, i dont know why.))

Comment: I second Ben West's answer. However, if the background image will always be the same, a workaround for this could be to set the image as a background image for the canvas (using CSS).

Answer (score 1):

Usually you do `clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)` and draw everything from scratch at every update.

The canvas is just a dumb bitmap with no concept of layers or different objects. You can't remove your character to reveal the background behind, that part of the background is gone. If you want to see it again you have to draw it again.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your help, but i found a way to do it self.

So, i would make a for loop, i = NANONAUT_HEIGHT, etc etc.
then i would clearRect, (Ben's answer) and then draw it again

Thanks again! and if anyone needs a code snippet, here you go.

```js
          if(NANONAUT_WIDTH <= canvas.height - 270){
      NANONAUT_WIDTH = NANONAUT_WIDTH - 30
      
      for(i = NANONAUT_HEIGHT; i < img.width; i++){
    c.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
          c.drawImage(spaceImg, 10,10);
      c.drawImage(nanonaut, NANONAUT_HEIGHT, NANONAUT_WIDTH)
      }
    }
```